# JNI program hanging

Tags: java, java-native-interface

In one of my Java projects I am expected to call a C function. As I am new to JNI, I first attempted a simple Helloworld program.

I wrote a class with a reference to a native method by name `sayHello()` which returns `void` and takes no argument. I compiled the class and generated the header file using the `javah` utility. I then copied over the signature of this function into a new C file as a new function and just called `printf("Hello, World!")` in that function. I generated a dll from it using `gcc` on my cygwin shell. I verified that the dll contained the function. I registered the dll using the `regsvr32` utility.

When I ran the java program to call the `sayHello()` function, the dll is getting loaded, which I verified by trying to delete the dll when this program was still running, but there is no response and the application seems to be waiting for something.

What could be the problem with this?

The source code is as follows:

```
/* Hello.java */
public class Hello
{
    static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("hello");
    }

    public native void sayHello();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Hello h = new Hello();
        h.sayHello();
    }
}
```

---

```
/* Hello.h */
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class Hello */

#ifndef _Included_Hello
#define _Included_Hello
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     Hello
 * Method:    sayHello
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Hello_sayHello
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

---

```
/* Hello.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jni.h>

#include "Hello.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Hello_sayHello
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
    printf("Hello, World!");
    return;
}
```

---

Comment: The code looks fine (very similar to http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/start.html). Could you please add some details about the way you compile the DLL and add some traces in your Java and C code?

Comment: try compiling with mingw. Also, you do not need to register the dll.

Comment: Can you please sum up the answer and mark it correct if you've found a solution?

Comment: I'd like to see an accepted answer for this one, too.  Are you able to remember the solution, @Shyam?

Comment: @PaulHicks I don't see "Pilgrim" whom I have thanked in the list of commenters here, probably "Pilgrim" has assumed a new name. Also, as this has been a very old question I am unable to recollect the context in which I raised it and what the solution was! I am sorry! :)