# c++ iostreams not working through JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface, g++, cygwin

I am creating a shared library Client.dll using Cygwin g++ compiler and calling through a JAVA program.

Everything is working fine if I remove 'cout <<' command from Client.c program. The method returns the value.  But when I add cout command the JVM freezes.

Client.c has :

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_nativeCode_Client_getDummyData(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jint pmuId)
{
    jint myint = 11;
    pmuId = pmuId + pmuId;
    cout <<"here";
    return myint;
}
```

I am creating .dll as,

```
$ g++ -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\include" -I"C:\Program Files    
    (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\include\win32" -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -shared -o Client.dll Client.c
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nitpick: `cout <<"here";` is a statement not a "command".

Comment: sorry, my mistake. After adding 'cout statement', java program just hangs.

Comment: I recall from doing this long ago that there was a fundamental incompatibility between cygwin iostreams and the JDK's standard output; I could get one or the other of them to display in a process, but not both. Not surprised if it was never solved.

Comment: this is same problem as this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438051/jni-program-hanging?rq=1 . But the solution is not provided there.

Comment: Are the cygwin dll accessible, i.e. in the PATH?